# SASS, SCSS, LESS, CSS, JS соотношения между ними

Tags: javascript, css, sass, less

Я не понимаю, в каком отношении находятся sass, less, js, css? Про js и css понимаю, разумеется. Кто занимается переводом sass, less в css? Это делает javascript?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Этим занимается [транслятор](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%A2%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%BD%D1%81%D0%BB%D1%8F%D1%82%D0%BE%D1%80) - программа преабразует синтаксис sass,less в css.

Судя по [github](https://github.com/sass) есть несколько имплиментаций.

Js и css особо друг к другу практически отношения никакого не имеют - язык программирования и язык стилей (теплое и мягкое)

Comment: Окей. Т.е. этот транслятор встроен в браузер? И это что-то, что работает под капотом и доступа к нему нет, верно?

Comment: нет, браузер только css понимает, ключевое слово "преабразует"

Comment: хотя можно сделать но большого смысла нет в этом

Comment: @hedgehogues сборщик собирает `sass`/`less` в `CSS`. Сборщики `Gulp` или `Webpack` этим занимаются.